# Conclude $\int\left(\frac12f''-(bf)'\right)\varphi=0$ from $\int(bf)\varphi'+\frac12f\varphi''=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $b\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ and $f,\varphi\in C^2(\mathbb R)$. Assume $$\int(b(x)f(x))\varphi'(x)+\frac12f(x)\varphi''(x){\rm d}x=0\tag1.$$ Why can we conclude that $$\int\left(\frac12f''(x)-(bf)'(x)\right)\varphi(x)\:{\rm d}x=0?\tag2$$ Obviously, some kind of integration by parts (maybe Greens formula) needs to be used. However, I'm not sure what we need to do and I think we need further assumptions (e.g. $\varphi\in C_c^\infty$).

Comment: Do you mean $f,\varphi\in C^{\color{red}{\bf 2}}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @Batominovski Yes, sorry.

Comment: I think you are right that we need more assumptions about $\varphi$ (assuming that the integral is done on the whole real line).  For example, if I take $\varphi(x):=x$, $f(x):=x^3$, and $b(x):=\exp(-x^2)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then (1) holds but (2) does not converge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me do half of that for you. Given that $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb R)$, there exists $M>0$ such that for all $n=0, 1, 2, \dots$ we have $\varphi^{(n)}(x)=0$ for all $x\ge M$. Hence
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\Bbb R} f(x)\varphi''(x)\, dx &= \int_{-M}^M f(x)\varphi''(x)\, dx \\
&= f(x)\varphi(x)\big\lvert_{x=-M}^M - \int_{-M}^M f'(x)\varphi'(x)\, dx \\
&= f(M)\varphi(M)-f(-M)\varphi(-M) - \int_{\Bbb R} f'(x)\varphi'(x)\, dx \\
&= 0-0 - \int_{\Bbb R} f'(x)\varphi'(x)\, dx \\
&= - \int_{\Bbb R} f'(x)\varphi'(x)\, dx.
\end{align}$$

You can see from the above that we use that fact that $\varphi$ has compact support to get rid of the boundary terms.

Can you finish the rest of the proof?